# How can i insert material icons into Material Theme Editor

Tags: material-design, sketchapp, google-material-icons

Firstly, i want to use icon from my theme editor library. but they request to download icon as i need in following picture.
[image: request to download]

i made download they give me `.sketch` file.
My question is that how can I insert that icon sketch file to my theme editor dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you download the icon set open it in Sketch then go in the top bar select `file -> add as library`. Once you've done that you can then select `plugins -> manage plugins -> libraries` in the top bar and you should see the icons in the list. Make sure the blue check mark is checked next to the icon library in the list. You should now see the icons in your symbol list when you insert new symbols.

The docs explain this fairly well.

> To use the Material icon sets in Theme Editor component symbols:
>
> Download an icon set from the icons tab of the editor panel. With the
>   icon file open, select File > Add as library. This will add the icon
>   set to your Sketch libraries. You can then pull added icons into any
>   component symbol through the Sketch override panel.